# How to check the status of detached thread in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have tried searching many ways for the solution, but couldn't find proper one, so far.

I am using detached thread because I don't want my main thread to wait/block for the new child thread as it has many other important things to do.

I create a thread as follows:

```
std::thread rsync_t(&PreCompile::RunPreCompileThr, obj, arg1, arg2);
rsync_t.detach();
```

Now, **Objective is to periodically check if this detached thread is active and running.**

I tried future/promise and async way to do this, but it requires .get() which is something similar to join(), which I don't want.

Any suggestions to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't detach, and don't wait :) use normal synchronisation mechanisms like mutex and condition_variable for signaling. Join the threads before program exit.

Comment: Yes, true. So is there any work around to do achieve this? Two separate threads running in parallel and one thread want to know status of other thread.

Comment: @user1228352 I don't understand what makes you think you need to `detach` to have the threads run in parallel. The other thread starts running as soon as you construct the `std::thread`. The _only_ case in which you have no parallelism is if you call `join` _immediately_. But why would you do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you detach a thread, then you have explicitly said "I don't need to wait for this thread to finish". This is usually because the thread *never* finishes, and keeps running until the end of the program.

In any case, `std::thread` doesn't provide a mechanism to poll to see if a thread has finished without waiting. To do that you would need to use an alternative mechanism, whether the thread is detached or not.

One option is to start the thread with `std::async(std::launch::async, func)` and use the returned future to check if the thread is still running.

```
auto future=std::async(std::launch::async,thread_func);
bool thread_is_still_running=future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0))!=std::future_status::ready;
```

If you use this option then you will need to keep the `future` object around (e.g. by storing it in a long-lived `std::vector` or a global variable), as its destructor will wait for the thread to finish.

Alternatively you can use a `std::mutex` and a boolean flag, or a `std::atomic<bool>` which is set from within the thread just before it exits, to indicate when the thread is done.

```
std::atomic<bool> done=false;

void thread_func(){
  do_stuff();
  done=true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you `detach` a `std::thread`, you lose the communication channel that the `std::thread` object provides:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach

> After calling detach `*this` no longer owns any thread.

If you want to communicate with the detached thread afterwards in any way, you need to do it manually. `std::thread` can no longer help you after `detach`.

> I am using detached thread because I don't want my main thread to wait/block for the new child thread as it has many other important things to do.

The proper solution likely does not involve `detach`. You don't need to `detach` to have the thread run in parallel, it runs in parallel already when the `std::thread` constructor returns. Just keep the `std::thread` object alive and query through it, and only call `join` when the thread is actually supposed to be done/end. That said, `std::thread` only provides [`joinable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) which only changes after `join`, so it doesn't provide the information you need (that your code is "done" in some form).

Answer (score 2):

With `std::async`, you have an option to retrieve task status from the future. It is not necessary to use `get()`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for

```
auto status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
    // Thread has finished
}
```